# Tagged Duplicate Entries After user submits the form Django

Tags: python, django

can someone help me figure out... I would want to automatically trigger in database if the entries that was posted by a different user is a possible duplicate. if entries like date, time and location are the same... how can I do this? Thank you

So far I have below code, where can I insert possible duplicate in the database after the user submits the form

**Model**

```
class UserReport(models.Model):
PENDING = 1
APPROVED = 2
REJECTED = 3
STATUS = (
    (PENDING, 'Pending'),
    (APPROVED, 'Approved'),
    (REJECTED, 'Rejected')
)

IF_DUPLICATE = (
    ('Duplicate', 'Duplicate'),
    ('Possible Duplicate', 'Possible Duplicate'),
    ('Not Duplicate', 'Not Duplicate')
)

user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
userid = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True,  null=True, blank=True)
# barangay = models.ForeignKey(Barangay_district, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
description = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
state = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
pin_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
latitude = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
longitude = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
geo_location = gismodels.PointField(blank=True, null=True, srid=4326) # New field
upload_photovideo = models.FileField(upload_to='incident_report/image', blank=True, null=True)
date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS, blank=True, null=True)
duplicate =  models.CharField(choices=IF_DUPLICATE,max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def get_status(self):
    if self.status == 1:
        incident_status = 'Pending'
    elif self.status == 2:
        incident_status = 'Approved'
    elif self.status == 3:
        incident_status = 'Rejected'
    return incident_status


# New method to generate geo_location from lat, lng


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserReport, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.upload_photovideo:
        if  ".jpg" in self.upload_photovideo.url or ".png" in self.upload_photovideo.url:
         #check if image exists before resize
            img = Image.open(self.upload_photovideo.path)

            if img.height > 1080 or img.width > 1920:
                new_height = 720
                new_width = int(new_height / img.height * img.width)
                img = img.resize((new_width, new_height))
                img.save(self.upload_photovideo.path)
    
    if self.latitude and self.longitude:
        self.geo_location = Point(float(self.longitude), float(self.latitude))
        return super(UserReport, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    return super(UserReport, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Views**

```
def sa_incidentreports(request):
profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form =  UserReportForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    form_general = IncidentGeneralForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    # form_people = IncidentRemarksForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    form_media = IncidentRemarksForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    form_remarks = IncidentRemarksForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    try:
        if form.is_valid() and form_general.is_valid() and form_remarks.is_valid():
            date=request.POST.get("date")
            time=request.POST.get("time")
            address=request.POST.get("address")
            city=request.POST.get("city")
            pin_code=request.POST.get("pin_code")
            latitude=request.POST.get("latitude")
            longitude=request.POST.get("longitude")
            description=request.POST.get("description")
            

            accident_factor1 = request.POST.get("accident_factor")
            accident_factor = AccidentCausation.objects.get(pk=accident_factor1)

            collision_type1 = request.POST.get("collision_type")
            collision_type = CollisionType.objects.get(pk=collision_type1)

            
            crash_type1 = request.POST.get("crash_type")
            crash_type = CrashType.objects.get(pk=crash_type1)
            
            weather = request.POST.get("weather")
            light = request.POST.get("light")
            severity = request.POST.get("severity")
            movement_code = request.POST.get("movement_code")
            
            
            desc=request.POST.getlist("desc[]")
            images=request.FILES.getlist("file[]")
            
            responder = request.POST.get("responder")
            action_taken = request.POST.get("action_taken")
            form.user = request.user
            user_report=UserReport(user=request.user,date=date,time=time,address=address,city=city,pin_code=pin_code,latitude=latitude,longitude=longitude,description=description)
            user_report.status = 2
            user_report.save()
            incident_general=IncidentGeneral(user_report=user_report,accident_factor=accident_factor,
                                            collision_type=collision_type,
                                            crash_type=crash_type,
                                            weather=weather,light=light,severity=severity,movement_code=movement_code)
            incident_general.save()
            
            incident_remarks = IncidentRemark(incident_general=incident_general,responder=responder,action_taken=action_taken)
            incident_remarks.save()
            
            messages.success(request,"Data Save Successfully")
            request.session['latest__id'] = incident_general.id
            return redirect('sa_incidentreports_additional')
        
    except Exception as e:
        print('invalid form')
        messages.error(request, str(e))


    else:
        print('invalid formd')
        print(form.errors)
        print(form_general.errors)
        print(form_remarks.errors)
else:
    form = UserReportForm()
    form_general = IncidentGeneralForm()
    form_remarks = IncidentRemarksForm()        
context = {
    'form': form,
    'form_general': form_general,
    'form_remarks': form_remarks,
    'profile':profile
}
return render(request,"pages/super/sa_incident_report.html", context)
```

Comment: Can you provide some code of what ypu have attempted so far? It's really not the place to ask how to do something, but why why something isn't working when you have attempted it. If there's some code you have which we can help you debug, please feel free to update the question. At the very least, we would need to see some model and view code that relates to those parts you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your models.py you can add unique together

```py
class UserReport(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('date','time','geo_location')
```

then migrate. This will restrict duplication.